# How do I get Rails to read environment variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-5, unicorn

I've installed Nginx and Unicorn and trying to get it to work with my Rails 5 application on Ubuntu 14.04.  I have a file in ~/myproject/config/secrets.yml which contains

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 547268978521e278fd572db969ce2d25cea9da7c6db4f7164942d02322177128704a4c76ed1f536dd7ac791b10ef0355b4542f21b128077657bdef156472ad81

test:
  secret_key_base: c1aae665f8ed25da55a457870526dcac878d5a3734ab2fd29b4ec32b4b31bbe2f16d3b72bf0cacf0c6c1c88e4862d35f45c2c10140d990388e5e2184459cd23e

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Yet when I restart nginx and unicorn and attempt to visit my web page, I get this error in my unicorn logs ...

```
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736220 #11291] ERROR -- : app error: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml` (RuntimeError)
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736414 #11291] ERROR -- : /home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:513:in `validate_secret_key_config!'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736462 #11291] ERROR -- : /home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736491 #11291] ERROR -- : /home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:693:in `build_request'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736515 #11291] ERROR -- : /home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:521:in `build_request'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736541 #11291] ERROR -- : /home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:521:in `call'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736646 #11291] ERROR -- : /home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:562:in `process_client'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736680 #11291] ERROR -- : /home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:658:in `worker_loop'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736709 #11291] ERROR -- : /home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:508:in `spawn_missing_workers'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736738 #11291] ERROR -- : /home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:132:in `start'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736767 #11291] ERROR -- : /home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/gems/unicorn-5.2.0/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736793 #11291] ERROR -- : /home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin/unicorn:22:in `load'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736818 #11291] ERROR -- : /home/rails/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin/unicorn:22:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736842 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736867 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736894 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736939 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:332:in `exec'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736968 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.736996 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.737021 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.737050 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.737078 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.737106 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:11:in `start'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.737136 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:34:in `block in <top (required)>'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.737170 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:100:in `with_friendly_errors'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.737200 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/exe/bundle:26:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.737230 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `load'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.737253 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.737266 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
E, [2017-04-09T22:37:34.737280 #11291] ERROR -- : /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

In my project directory, /home/rails/myproject/.rbenv-vars, I have defined

```
SECRET_KEY_BASE=secretbase
APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD=apppassword
```

How do I get Rails to incorporate these values into the environment, or is there some other place I shoudl be putting these values?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `export SECRET_KEY_BASE=secretbase` in shell
2. Use Figaro Gem, I use it
3. Use a local_env.yml File

More info here: [rails environment variables](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html)

Comment: For #1, where am I putting that?.  For #2, is there anything more to do than simply including that gem in my Gemfile.  And for #3, am I using local_env.yml instead of config/secrets.xml?

Comment: For #1 in the command you run rails. For #2 use show create a config file which you can get instruction in the gem's Github. For #3 you still need it. local_env.yml is just a way to manage use env variables.

Answer (score 0):

To declare env variable, you can add this to `SECRET_KEY_BASE=secretbase` .bashrc or .bash_profile in your home folder or export `SECRET_KEY_BASE=secretbase` in shell.

Now second point, to use it in yml file you should change extension of your `yml` file to `yml.erb` if you don't want to use any other Gem for this.because Rails need to know you are using ruby code in yml file.`<%= %>'` is a way to call var and methods in Rails so extension should be `yml.erb`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how rails read env variable `<%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>`
To fix your error you should supply the value for `SECRET_KEY_BASE`.
For this, you can use any of the following methods
1. Simply export using the shell. `export SECRET_KEY_BASE=secretvalue`
2. Create a .yml in `config/` and load in `application.rb`
3. Use gems like `figaro, dotenv`